# Why Zend Lucene returns all hits if nothing is found?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, zend-lucene

I have this query: `+document_type:client name:something to search` and if `something to search` is not found the Zend Lucene returns all documents containing `+document_type:client` and I would like to return empty set.

I've tried to add `AND` operator between terms, but result is the same.

What I'ma doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ensure both comparisons are matched,
you can applied `+` to both comparisons

```
+document_type:client +name:some_value
```

OR

```
+(document_type:client name:some_value)
```

Take a look on

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/> <-- change it to AND
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I still don't get why the AND operator added explicitly in query dont work for me

Comment: What is your original query? does the search terms are with spaces?